# How to calculate system memory usage from /proc/meminfo (like htop)

Tags: linux, memory, htop

Running the `htop` command gives you a picture of the memory usage in a format like this:

```
1.92G/5.83G
```

**Question:** how should I interpret the values taken from `/proc/meminfo` in order to calculate programmatically the memory used?

I am looking for something similar to this: [Accurate calculation of CPU usage given in percentage in Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23367857/accurate-calculation-of-cpu-usage-given-in-percentage-in-linux) meaning that pseudocode is ok, I do not need something that can be compiled, just the logic. The source code of htop is a place to look for but I had no luck spotting the lines of code written for this...

```
$ cat /proc/meminfo 
MemTotal:        6110716 kB
MemFree:         2076448 kB
MemAvailable:    3800944 kB
Buffers:          382240 kB
Cached:          1496216 kB
SwapCached:            0 kB
Active:          2830192 kB
Inactive:         796648 kB
Active(anon):    1749940 kB
Inactive(anon):   109808 kB
Active(file):    1080252 kB
Inactive(file):   686840 kB
Unevictable:          48 kB
.
.
.
...
```

Comment: That depends on how accurate a picture you're wanting. For the `1.92G/5.83G` stats you quote, simply take the numbers in the first two lines and convert from kB to GB (i.e. divide by 1024*1024)... Most of the rest of the lines are simply a breakdown of what's currently in use base on how it's being used, whether it's been modified or not, and a few other characteristics...

Comment: Hi @twalberg, thanks for your reply. So you are proposing something like [MemUsed] = [MemTotal] - [MemAvailable]?

Comment: I'm not really proposing anything, because it's not clear what kind of "picture" you're actually looking for. That might be a reasonable estimate, but it's not going to be exact - memory accounting in Linux (or really any significant OS, for that matter) is complex and not easily reduced to an equation in two variables...

Comment: the **free** command dumps the same as /proc/meminfo.

Answer (score 99, accepted):

htop author here. These are the calculations I make to get the numbers for the green, blue and yellow bars in the memory meter:

- Total used memory = `MemTotal` - `MemFree`
- Non cache/buffer memory (green) = Total used memory - (Buffers + Cached memory)
- Buffers (blue) = `Buffers`
- Cached memory (yellow) = `Cached` + `SReclaimable` - `Shmem`
- Swap = `SwapTotal` - `SwapFree`

In the htop source code: [linux/LinuxProcessList.c](https://github.com/hishamhm/htop/blob/8af4d9f453ffa2209e486418811f7652822951c6/linux/LinuxProcessList.c#L802-L833) and [linux/Platform.c](https://github.com/hishamhm/htop/blob/1f3d85b6174f690a7e354bbadac19404d5e75e78/linux/Platform.c#L198-L208).

[image: htop screenshot]

Comment: How about blue? Also, what is « Buffers »?

Comment: Sorry, buffers was mislabeled yellow, it is blue. `man proc` says this about Buffers: "Relatively temporary storage for raw disk blocks that shouldn't get tremendously large"

Comment: @NicolasWormser [30% of RAM is “buffers”. What is it?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/440558/30-of-ram-is-buffers-what-is-it)

Comment: Why do you subtract shared memory from the cached memory (`Cached` + `SReclaimable` **- `Shmem`**)? The `top` command doesn't seem to do this for its `buff/cache` calculation.

Comment: @MattK, if I had to guess, it's probably because `Shmem` is included in the number for `Cached`, and he feels that it shouldn't count as true cached memory.

Comment: If used memory(green) has 2GB and I killed a process which has RSS 400MB. Why the used memory becomes 500M after I kill this process? Is another physical memory located beyond the RSS?