# Discrepancy between values in htop and /proc/meminfo

Tags: linux, memory, proc, htop

From the author of htops answer
[How to calculate system memory usage from /proc/meminfo (like htop)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41224738/how-to-calculate-system-memory-usage-from-proc-meminfo-like-htop/41251290#41251290)

I got to know that the total memory in htop is calculated from /proc/meminfo. I think I could crosscheck this in code as well and it checks out.
However compared to memory bar in htop. I see a major difference in the memory values shown in /proc/meminfo.

In my /proc/meminfo the memory consumption reads

```
MemTotal:       4144807288 kB
MemFree:        3513532764 kB
MemAvailable:   3936769368 kB
Buffers:         1119392 kB
```

So the Total used memory , which I think represented by the memory bar should be MemTotal-MemFree in GBs which should be (4144807288-3513532764)/1024^2=602Gb as far as I understand.
However for me this value shows almost 180Gb. Could anyone explain how the values in /proc/meminfo and one in htop would become different.
[image]

Comment: [so] is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Unix and its utilities. [unix.se] or [su] would be better places for questions like this.

Answer (score 1):

Let me first say holy moley that's an insane amount of RAM.

Anyway, there's something not being understood here:

"Memory free" is totally unused memory.

"Memory available" is the amount of memory that's totally unused ("Memory free" above) + memory that could be freed in an instant if the kernel dropped its file system caches. Generally, *available memory* is the stat you should look at / care about.

Using the "Memory available" stat in our calculations instead, let's calculate:

```bash
numfmt --to=iec $(((4144807288-3936769368)*1024))
> 199G
```

Much closer to the 180G `htop` displays as the amount of "used" RAM.

Try also running `free -h` and look under the "available" column.

Comment: This makes more sense, but I find it intruiging as in the htop authors post and htop source code MemFree is used for the computation, as in https://github.com/hishamhm/htop/blob/master/linux/LinuxProcessList.c#L961C4-L961C46