# How to extract CPU load of cores from htop command?

Tags: linux, shell

I have found that *htop* command was the only way to display nicely each CPU core's load. I need an average of each CPU core from the last few seconds. However, I do not know how to extract those numbers in a command line. For example, using *grep* or *-n 1*. I am running Ångström where I am not allowed to install any more extra packages.

I would like my end result to be:

```
CPU0: X%
CPU1: X%
```

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get overall CPU Usage (e.g. 57%) on Linux](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9229333/how-to-get-overall-cpu-usage-e-g-57-on-linux)

Comment: I found the answer in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23367857/accurate-calculation-of-cpu-usage-given-in-percentage-in-linux/ "link") where it calculates accurate cpu given in percentage.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `htop` which is more of a gui, go straight to /proc/stat and grab what you need.

Using awk:

```
awk '$1~/cpu[0-9]/{usage=($2+$4)*100/($2+$4+$5); print $1": "usage"%"}' /proc/stat
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it calculates the average since last reboot. I need an average of the last few seconds. How would I go about it?

Comment: `/proc/stat` info for anyone who is interested http://www.linuxhowtos.org/System/procstat.htm

Comment: Does not use htop.

Comment: @JongwookChoi That was not a requirement from OP. If that is a requirement for you, then it would be prudent to open a new question and note that limitation.