# How can I display an accurate calculation of CPU use in percent

Tags: linux, bash, awk, cpu-usage

I'm aware this question has been asked numerous times over
but unfortunately none of the given answers seem to work for what I need.

Everyone seems to recommend `/proc/stat` however I can't seem to find 1 answer that works as expected:
[image]
as you can see here, core 0 reports being 16% used even though it's actually only 3% used
in fact it doesn't matter if it's 100%, it still reports 16% with only a 0.01%-0.02% increase

I've also tested another approach with only `$2+$4 +$5` rather than the whole range, but even that returned inaccurate results...

How do CPU monitors, like the graph above, derive their information??
because it doesn't appear to be through `/proc/stat` unless everyone's doing something wrong.

notable resources:

- [Accurate calculation of CPU usage given in percentage in Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23367857/accurate-calculation-of-cpu-usage-given-in-percentage-in-linux)
- [How to get overall CPU usage (e.g. 57%) on Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9229333/how-to-get-overall-cpu-usage-e-g-57-on-linux)
- https://devbest.com/threads/linux-scripting-with-xfce4-panels-generic-monitor-applet.89845/

I've looked through much more, but they all pretty much point to the same things.

As for the script, I know it's a bit messy, I don't work with bash much, but here it is:

```
#!/bin/bash
H=($(awk '/MHz/{printf "%.2fGHz|", $4/1000}' /proc/cpuinfo))
A=($(awk 'FNR>1 && FNR<4 {
    i=$5+$6; printf "%d|%d\n", i, i+$2+$3+$4+$7+$8+$9
}' /proc/stat))
sleep 0.125
awk -v a="${A[*]}" -v h="${H[*]}" -v n="0" 'FNR>1 && FNR<4 {
    n++
    split(h,s,"|"); split(a,p,"|")
    i=$5+$6; t=(i+$2+$3+$4+$7+$8+$9)-p[n,1]
    printf "%s: %s %.2f%\n", $1, s[n], ((t-(i-p[n,0]))/t)*100
}' /proc/stat
```

pretty much all of it was followed from other answers...

If there's a better way to do any of this (such as merging `cpuinfo` with `stat`, or not needlessly splitting an array to prevent `s[n]` from reporting a scalar error, or even sleeping and re-reading within awk), by all means please improve. :)

Comment: What are `p[n,1]` and `p[n,0]`?

Comment: @JamesBrown `p` is a split array from `A`: `split(a,p,"|")`, where the result is basically `( idle, total )`, check the python source from the first notable resource for more info. ;)

Comment: if you dont understand `split()` (it threw me off as well), here's it's equivalent in python `p = tuple( v.split("|") for v in a )` or in other words `( "idle|total", ... ) -> ( ( idle, total ), ... )`

Comment: I understand `split(a,p,"|")` after there will be `a[1],a[2]...` but not `a[1,1]` unless you explicitly define it which I can't see you doing.

Comment: right because the result from `a[1]` is `"idle|total"` (or at least it should be, where bash doesn't agree), which I've already tried every way I could think of to create `A` as a 2D array, and I can't find anything on creating 2D arrays, or what's even worse is you can't even access `a[n]` because that thinks `a` is a scalar.