# golang CPU usage

Tags: go, ps, psutil, htop

I am aware of [[1]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11356330/getting-cpu-usage-with-golang). With a few lines of code, I just want to extract the current CPU usage from the top n processes with the most CPU usages. More or less the top 5 rows of [top](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/top.1.html). Using *github.com/shirou/gopsutil/process* this is straight-forward:

```
// file: gotop.go
package main

import (
  "log"
  "time"
  "sort"

  "github.com/shirou/gopsutil/process"
)


type ProcInfo struct{
  Name  string
  Usage float64
} 

type ByUsage []ProcInfo

func (a ByUsage) Len() int      { return len(a) }
func (a ByUsage) Swap(i, j int) { a[i], a[j] = a[j], a[i] }
func (a ByUsage) Less(i, j int) bool {
  return a[i].Usage > a[j].Usage
}


func main() {

  for {
    processes, _ := process.Processes()

    var procinfos []ProcInfo
    for _, p := range processes{
      a, _ := p.CPUPercent()
      n, _ := p.Name()
      procinfos = append(procinfos, ProcInfo{n, a})
    }
    sort.Sort(ByUsage(procinfos))

    for _, p := range procinfos[:5]{
      log.Printf("   %s -> %f", p.Name, p.Usage)
    }
    time.Sleep(3 * time.Second)
  }
}
```

While the refresh rate in this implementation *gotop* is 3 seconds like *top* does, *gotop* has approx. 5-times higher demand on CPU usage to get these values like *top* does. Is there any trick to more efficiently read the 5 topmost consuming processes? I also tried to find the implementation of *top* to see how this is implemented there.

Is *psutils* responsible for this slown-down? I found as [cpustat](https://github.com/uber-common/cpustat) implemented in GO as well. But even `sudo ./cpustat -i 3000 -s 1` seems to be not as efficient as `top`.

The main motivation is to monitor the usage of the current machine with a fairly small amount of computational effort so that it can run as a service in the background.

It seems, even *htop* is [only reading](https://github.com/hishamhm/htop/blob/master/linux/LinuxProcessList.c#L96) */proc/stat*.

**edit**
as proposed in the comments here is the result when profiling

```
Showing top 10 nodes out of 46 (cum >= 70ms)
      flat  flat%   sum%        cum   cum%
      40ms 40.00% 40.00%       40ms 40.00%  syscall.Syscall
      10ms 10.00% 50.00%       30ms 30.00%  github.com/shirou/gopsutil/process.(*Process).fillFromStatusWithContext
      10ms 10.00% 60.00%       30ms 30.00%  io/ioutil.ReadFile
      10ms 10.00% 70.00%       10ms 10.00%  runtime.slicebytetostring
      10ms 10.00% 80.00%       20ms 20.00%  strings.FieldsFunc
      10ms 10.00% 90.00%       10ms 10.00%  syscall.Syscall6
      10ms 10.00%   100%       10ms 10.00%  unicode.IsSpace
         0     0%   100%       10ms 10.00%  bytes.(*Buffer).ReadFrom
         0     0%   100%       70ms 70.00%  github.com/shirou/gopsutil/process.(*Process).CPUPercent
         0     0%   100%       70ms 70.00%  github.com/shirou/gopsutil/process.(*Process).CPUPercentWithContext
```

Seems like the syscall takes forever. A tree dump is here:
https://gist.github.com/PatWie/4fa528b7d7b1d0b5c1b665c056671477

This changes the question into:
- Is the syscall the issue?
- Are there any c-sources for the `top` program? I just found the implementation of htop
- Is there an easy fix? I consider to write it in c and just wrap it for go.

Comment: Please profile it so we can determine which part is the bottle-neck.

Comment: Just a thought: `top` is a venerable ancient (read: optimized over and over again, even with a complete rewrite, iirc) and written in C (no GC and alike). As always with programming languages: Go is awesome for _some_ things, not for _everything_.

Comment: I added the result from profiling. Is my conclusion correct? Further, I did not found the implementation of `top`.

Comment: It seems, that golang is indeed very inefficient or at least the library `github.com/shirou/gopsutil/process` *for my use case*. I ended up by implementing it directly in c and just calling it by cgo, see https://github.com/PatWie/cpuinfo

Comment: I googled "top source code" and found: https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/tools/perf/builtin-top.c

Answer (score 0):

`github.com/shirou/gopsutil/process` uses `ioutil.ReadFile` which access the filesystem less efficiently than top. In particular, `ReadFile`:

- calls `Stat` which adds an extra unnecessary Syscall.
- uses `os.Open` instead of `unix.Openat` + `os.NewFile` which causes extra kernel time traversing `/proc` when resolving the path. `os.NewFile` is still a little inefficient since it always checks whether the file descriptor is non-blocking. This can be avoided by using the `golang.org/x/sys/unix` or `syscall` packages directly.

Retrieving process details under Linux is fairly inefficient in general (lots of filesystem scanning, marshalling text data). However, you can achieve similar performance to `top` with Go by fixing the filesystem access (as described above).