# Retrieve information from Linux kernel virtual filesystem

Tags: linux, go, zfs

I am wanting to write a utility that does some reporting based on data available in the /proc directory.

Is this as simple as reading and parsing the contents of the virtual file I am interested in?  I have seen this approach implemented in Python when doing similar things.

Is there a superior way to do this in Go?

For backstory, I am using ZFS on Linux and want to retrieve data from this virtual file: /proc/spl/kstat/zfs/arcstats

This is a Python program that operates directly on that file.

Comment: > Is this as simple as reading and parsing the contents of the virtual file I am interested in?
As far as I know: yes.  But you might try looking at https://github.com/c9s/goprocinfo to see what they do there, or if you can use that package instead.

Comment: @jrefior You should transform your comment in a full answer.

Answer (score 0):

> Is this as simple as reading and parsing the contents of the virtual file I am interested in?

As far as I know: yes.

But you might try looking at [github.com/c9s/goprocinfo](https://github.com/c9s/goprocinfo) to see what they do there, or if you can use that package instead.

See also [this SO question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20033735/1964690).